# how to copy text from xterm based terminal to some other gui application on linux

Tags: copy, x11, xterm

i use uxrvt ( for those who dont know, its terminal emulator based on xterm).

i know its easy to copy/paste stuff from terminal to itself is a trivial thing. it can be done by mouse left click to select and middle click to paste.

but in my case i need to copy text from terminal to another application, viz on google chromium. how can i do that. is it even possible? anyone?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/232744/how-to-copy-text-from-xterm-based-terminal-to-some-other-gui-application-on-linux).

Comment: @Dennis: sorry, wont do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Linux applications allow middle mouse button to paste. I know that chromium does. Your other alternative is to right-click on the terminal for a context menu. uxrvt might be so old that it doesn't support traditional copy/paste. And they are stored in different buffers, which is handy.

Comment: ohh thanks! it works.. :) my reason to chose uxrvt is its quite light weight w/o many dependencies.